# Using Excel VBA to run SQL query and getting error

Tags: sql-server, vba, excel

I am new to VBA. I would like to run simple SQL query from vba code. I found   simple looking code for this task, but i am keep getting error
"automation error unspecified error 2147647259 (80004005)"
I am stuck, please help  (user name and password were masked). 
here is my code:

```
Sub Download_Standard_BOM()  
Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection  
Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset  
Dim ConnectionString As String  
Dim StrQuery As String  
    ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Password=13139797MMn;Persist   Security Info=True;User ID=MPam;Data Source=172.20.84.15;Use Procedure   for Prepare=1;Auto Translate=True;Packet Size=4096;Use Encryption for   Data=False;Tag with column collation when possible=False;Initial   Catalog=ImportHapoalim"  
    cnn.Open ConnectionString    
    cnn.CommandTimeout = 900    
    StrQuery = "SELECT MAX(CAST(itra as float)) FROM [ImportHapoalim].[dbo].[Minchali] WHERE deltaid = 275"     
    rst.Open StrQuery, cnn    
    Sheets(1).Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rst  

End Sub
```

Comment: What you want to achieve. At which line you are getting this error.

Comment: you should obfuscate your IP and password (and change the pwd now it's been published)

Comment: "user name and password were masked"  this is not the true username, pass and ip...

Comment: I want to run the sql script from my excel file and get to results to the spreadsheet. it dose not say on which like the error is...

Comment: Do you have oracle client installed on your machine?

Comment: If you are indeed new to VBA you should really start with using the language itself without SQL. 
Can you write a for-next loop?
Can you write a do-while loop?
Can you handle errors (without the newbie error On Error Resume Next?)

Comment: i dont have oracle, this is SQL server db

Comment: i am a long time user of sql, the point of me using vba is to run my sql queries automatically and to output the results to the spreadsheet. All the programming is being done with SQL

Comment: rst.Open StrQuery, ConnectionString

Comment: still nothing :(